# Scrollbars in the tbody section of vaadin-grid (vaadin flow)

Tags: scrollbar, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

Is it possible, that the scrollbars for the vaadin-grid are only visible in the tbody-section, not in the whole grid-component?

[This is the current version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZO82.png)

[This is what I'd like to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8Q7N.png)

Comment: I don't think so because the scroller div is around the table and not inside the table

Comment: Yeah no, not doable – there are technical reasons for this structure.